# Reduce application database queries by using PostgreSQL's LISTEN/NOTIFY?

Tags: sql, postgresql, session, redis, backend

I am currently developing both back and frontend for a web application. The backend (Python/PostgreSQL/Redis) is basically a RESTish server which provides APIs for user management and other things.

The thing I would like to optimize is the following:

Whenever a user logs-in, a session token is generated for the user and saved on the client's browser. The session token is also the key in a redis database which holds information like the user id, expiration, ip, ...
For every API-request a database query is made to check if the user has the privileges or if the account has been locked or whatever.
The problem is that I can't store these information in the redis database because of synchronization issues (The admin can modify the user account at any time).

As I said, for every API-request the database is queried again. I would like to eliminate this by somehow lazily querying the database.

I've read that there is an API for PostgreSQL which can emit events for connection sessions (LISTEN/NOTIFY). One could combine this with a TRIGGER so the backend knows when a session token can be invalidated and updated.

I am not sure if this is the right approach, considering how this will scale.

Comment: Couldn't you trigger a Redis update every time the account is modified in the DB ? So you never had to look at the DB for validation. Another way, less efficient, to go would be to set up a session timeout on Redis so when there's a request, if there is a delta time ellapsed from last request, you fetch account info from DB into Redis, else you just assume Redis is updated.

Comment: The issue is that the "other" backend can access and modify the database too while being separated from the redis instance.